# How to resize the block in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

> I want to add some details in new line but I cannot do that .It is just moving on to next block

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! Can you please add more details like code snippet, what you already tried ? And what actually you're looking for (visuals). For details , advise to visit : [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shiva,  like VibrantVivek said more information would make it easier to get you the exact answer you are looking for.  However, if you are trying to add text in a new line, but the same paragraph in a text block, try `shift + enter`